# An argument active_directory is not expected here in terraform Azure app

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, terraform-provider-azure

i want to add `auth_settings` into my Azure App Service. I am using this provider:

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/windows_function_app

And this is my code. Module:

```
resource "azurerm_windows_function_app" "function_app" {
  name                 = var.name
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  location             = var.location
  storage_account_name = var.storage_account_name
  service_plan_id      = var.service_plan_id
  app_settings         = var.app_settings

  auth_settings {
    enabled          = var.auth_settings_enabled
    active_directory = var.auth_active_directory
  }
}
```

And `variables.tf` file:

```
// ommited the rest
variable "auth_settings_enabled" {
    type = bool
    default = false
}

variable "auth_active_directory" {
    default = null
    type = object({
        client_id         = optional(string)
        client_secret     = optional(string)
        allowed_audiences = optional(list(string))
    })
}
```

Then, i declare my module in `main.tf`

```
/// 
module "function_app_1" {
  source = "./function-app-module"

  // standard vars like name etc here...

  auth_settings_enabled = true
  auth_active_directory = {
    client_id         = var.clientid
    client_secret     = var.clientsecret
    allowed_audiences = [ var.audience ]
  }
}

module "function_app_2" {
  source = "./function-app-module"

  // standard vars like name etc here...
 
  auth_active_directory = {}
}
```

And after `terraform plan` commend i am getting this error:

```
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│
│   on function-app\main.tf line 28, in resource "azurerm_windows_function_app" "function_app":
│   28:     active_directory = var.auth_active_directory
│
│ An argument named "active_directory" is not expected here. Did you mean to define a block of type "active_directory"?
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│
│   on function-app\main.tf line 28, in resource "azurerm_windows_function_app" "function_app":
│   28:     active_directory = var.auth_active_directory
│
│ An argument named "active_directory" is not expected here. Did you mean to define a block of type "active_directory"?
```

My question is, how to init `active_directory` in `auth_settings` object properly?

Comment: It can't work that way, you cannot assign a variable value to an argument that is a block.

Comment: @MarkoE so what should I do? I want to `active directory` be optional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `active_directory` is a block and not an argument, you cannot define it the way you are currently trying to. So, there are a couple of things to consider:

1. If the `enabled` value is set to `true` the `active_directory` block should be used
2. Variable value assignment to a block rather than an argument

Based on the two assumptions, you could refactor the code block in question like this:

```
  auth_settings {
    enabled          = var.auth_settings_enabled
    dynamic "active_directory" {
      for_each = auth_settings_enabled ? [1] : []
      content {
        client_id         = var.auth_active_directory.client_id
        client_secret     = var.auth_active_directory.client_secret
        allowed_audiences = var.auth_active_directory.allowed_audiences
      }
    }
  }
```

In this case, Terraform `dynamic` block is used [1] to make sure the `active_directory` block is optional and used only when the `auth_settings_enabled` variable is equal to `true`.

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks